# Aumentar o tamanho das imagens de uma loja virtual

Tags: html, css

Queria aumentar essas imagens de produtos, eu consegui aumentar o tamanho, mas ele corta parte da imagem na largura e fica ruim, a disposição das imagens é muito junta. Alguém sabe como aumentar o espaçamento dos produtos?

Não sei se fiz certo. Não sou programador, sei bem pouco e vou mexendo, se tiver uma solução agradeço. E se tiver como aumentar a largura da página inteira também.

```
.product .product-image {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.product .product-image img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Aqui da pra ver os produtos e o código pelo inspecionar.

https://reacendamodafeminina.commercesuite.com.br/loja/loja.php?loja=497572&opencode_theme=5874e9ec537b0

Comment: Eu acho que vc deveria aumentar o container(DIV que abriga as imagens) que fica as imagens. As imagens não aumentam na largura pois estão sem espaço pra se ajustarem.

Answer (score 1):

De fato para aumentar a altura da imagem você precisa aumentar proporcionalmente a largura. Uma dica seria mostrar menos item por vez em cada linha, 2 ao invés de 3.
Para isso, se possível, você precisa mudar o HTML da lista que exibe os produtos.

De

```
<li class="col-sm-4" data-tray-tst="vitrine_produto"> ... </li>
```

Para

```
<li class="col-sm-6" data-tray-tst="vitrine_produto"> ... </li>
```

O resultado seria algo parecido com o print abaixo. Fiz alguns ajustes na css, mas o problema mesmo é a largura disponível para exibir os produtos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Minha dica seria realmente alterar a largura da pagina: aumentar para 1300px;

```
<div class="row">

element.style {
   width: 1300px;
}
```

E retirar as bordas laterais da div da imagem:

```
class="product";
```